# Why won't Apple allow users to access iCloud online via an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, iwork

Try this on your iPhone.

Go to www.iCloud.com . You can try it on Safari or Chrome.

Apple won't let you access the online version of iCloud.

On Chrome for iPhone, there's something called "Request Desktop Version." If you try that, Apple will redirect the site to www.Apple.com

Reason I want to access iCloud online: I don't have the iWork apps installed on my iPhone. So, I wanted to try out the web apps on iCloud (via my iPhone) and test them.

Why won't Apple let anyone do this. Anyone have any clue?

Comment: Lots of people could speculate, but is there a more specific and concrete problem you are trying to solve that perhaps we can help with?

Comment: @bmike I know where to post when there is. By the way, do you happen to own this website?

Comment: No ownership for me. The community moderates the website, sometimes sharpening the question is enough to get it reopened and also on occasion people mistake his for official apple support and are just looking for that site.

Answer (score 1):

- Because iCloud.com has not been optimised for a mobile screen size and for touchscreen controls.
- Because they want to promote 'the correct way'

  - Adding the iCloud account to Settings for access to Mail, etc.
  - Using the App Store apps for iWork

Comment: I was hoping they would have replicated the iWork apps' UI on the web app version of iWork.